# Running Moodle on Windows 2008 Server other than Webmatrix

Tags: windows-server-2008, moodle, iis-express

I am an educator and not a tech savvy but managed to install a Moodle installation in Windows 2008 server for the local network via the following environment:

> WebMatrix Version 3.0: 7.1.1934.0 IIS Express: 8.0.8418.0 .NET
>   Framework: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR Web Deploy:
>   7.1.1762.0 Web Platform Installer: 7.1.50430.0 ASP.NET Web Pages: 2.0.20715.0

The Webmatrix seems to be discontinued and I could not find solution to support php versions above 5.5. The site seems to be very slow and takes more time when more number of students access the site (at present concurrent users are about 50 and in total about 350 users) . The present server configuration are: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Intel xeon, 10GB, 64 Bit

Is there any tool similar to webmatrix GUI where I can start, stop and manage sites in addition with configuring url binding etc. so that it can be accessed through intranet? Could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS (internet information services) to configure your moodle server instead of WebMatrix. It is user friendly enough.